# Libre Office/Writer PDF export: white borders appear between lines even after setting borders to none

Tags: pdf, display, preview, libreoffice-writer

My document prints okay (exactly as it appears on the screen in Libre Office), but when I export to PDF and view the PDF on screen there are white borders around each text or picture object.

Here's a sample snapshot from PDF/Preview:

[image]

I've tried selecting a paragraph and changing the border property to None as described in [Libre Office help](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Borders), setting the "Line arrangement Default" to "Set no borders".

But borders set by the Format dialog don't correspond to the borders I see in PDF/Preview.  In PDF/Preview the border appears on line boundaries.  Borders set in Format appear around each picture, for example.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. Please report it [here](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/BugReport).

Answer (score 0):

A little old here, but I was still experiencing this bug the other day.  I found that sometime during the PDF conversion, LibreOffice had randomly added several Paragraph borders to my document.  I did Format-->Paragraph-->Borders, then **set** a border, clicked OK, then went back to the paragraph borders and unset the borders.  I re-exported the PDF and it looked fine.

Far from ideal but it worked for me